# Generating an ascending list of numbers of arbitrary length in python

Tags: python, list, range

Is there a function I can call that returns a list of ascending numbers? I.e., `function(10)` would return `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

```
def my_func(min, max)->list:     
    return list(range(min, max))
```

Comment: Answer is so tiny, and making it into a function would look like:
`def my_func(min, max):
    return list(range(min, max))`

Comment: @jupiar your comment should be the top level answer

Comment: This answer needs to be updated. Because in Python 3 (I think):

Answer (score 12):

`range(10)` is built in.

Answer (score 10):

If you want an iterator that gives you a series of indeterminate length, there is `itertools.count()`. Here I am iterating with `range()` so there is a limit to the loop.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for x, y in zip(range(10), itertools.count()):
...     print x, y
... 
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

---

Later: also, range() returns an iterator, not a list, in python 3.x. in that case, you want `list(range(10))`.